# How do I make sure I run a command for an exact amount of time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I created 3 command blocks that are always on repeat, but the problem is I don't have access to the command blocks doing the commands once the command has started. Is there a way for the command to be done for 15sec (for example) and then stop the command from being executed regardless of any other conditions?

I tried to use lever with redstone but the result was not exactly what I was looking for. The start is perfect but the ending can give me extremely different results based on how long the command was active for since I don't have access to the command block or lever.

Currently this is what I have: When the lever is activated, do the command until the lever is deactivated.

Comment: Only cos I am on break atm and don't have the time to post a proper answer: set up a "t-flip-flip" with a "hopper timer"

Comment: @Ben Can you give me links that explain t-flip-flip and hopper-timer?

Comment: [T-Flip-Flop](https://redstone.fandom.com/wiki/T_Flip-Flop) and [Hopper Clock](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Redstone_circuits/Clock/hopper_clock)

Answer (score 1):

As with many things that need a timer, you have [multiple options](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/questions/blockdelay/). The easiest in this case is probably a scoreboard timer.

For this, you'll need to set up a dummy scoreboard:

```
scoreboard objectives add timer dummy
```

Now, you can use a [fake player](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/questions/fakeplayer) to store the current duration that the command has been running for, by counting up the fake players score by 1 every [tick](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tick). Next you can check the score using `execute if score` and only run whatever command you want to run if the score is below the maximum duration (in this case it's 15 seconds * 20 ticks per second = 300).

```
scoreboard players add #duration timer 1
execute if score #duration timer matches ..300 run <your command>
```

and then to make the command run again, set the `#duration timer` score to 0.

Comment: It counts the number but it does not the command at all. I have an orange block with 2 purple ones.

Comment: "does not the command" you mean it doesn't execute the command? And why are you using an impulse commandblock if you want a command to run repeatedly for 15 seconds instead of a repeating commandblock? Maybe you should tell us the commands you actually want to run for us to be able to help you better.

Comment: the orange command is being executed normally along with the first purple block which does this command `(scoreboard players add #duration timer 1)` but the second purple block and the main command does not execute. `execute if score #duration timer matches ..300 run <your command>`

Comment: @GroxDots you need to replace `<your command>` with whatever command you want to run. You should [have a setup like this](https://i.imgur.com/nRroPsd.png) (all unconditional and always active; as many green ones as you need to run commands) where the first (blue) command is the `scoreboard players add` and the green one(s) are the `execute if score .... run <your command>` commands.

Comment: How many are for my command? Because I need only one if it is strictly for my command.

Comment: Just one then. The above image was just an example setup. If you need just one command, use just one chain commandblock.